# BigQuery: Is there any solution to integrate a BigQuery BI engine to BigQuery Client?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-bi-engine

We have a use case for low latency solutions to power our custom dashboard and leverage the BI engine.

I could see that the BI engine is enabled only for Data Studio and Looker.

Is there any solution to integrate a BigQuery BI engine to BigQuery Client?

Comment: Are you registered to the private preview?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere from the documentation I see that there is no registration process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no registration for BI Engine coupled with Looker or Datastudio. But, to access to the SQL interface, you must be registered.

> Access to the BI Engine SQL interface during preview is provided through an enrollment process. For details, see the BI Engine preview enrollment document.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/sql-interface-overview#obtaining_access_to_the_preview) the link in the documentation